# menu toggle not functioning jquery

Tags: jquery

On clicking the `li` or `href`, the menu should open. It's a horizontal menu with one `ul` and multiple `li`'s contained in a `div`. Might be able to do it with multiple `ul`'s but I would rather not, as it is too code heavy.

HTML

```
   <ul id="mainmenu" style="width:720px">

    <!-- 1Open -->
          <li id="mainmenudrop"><a href class="drop">helloooo</a>
             <div style="width:200px height:40px; background:#000000;">hmmmmfyhyf
</div>
         </li>
    <!-- 1 Close -->
    <!-- 2nd Open -->
         <li><a href="" class="drop">hello</a>
            <div style="width100px; height:40px; background:#000000;">
              yhythyytyt
              </div>
            </div></li> 
    <!-- 2nd Close --> 
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var toggleMenu = function(e) {
        var self = $(this),
            elemType = self[0].tagName.toLowerCase(),
            //get caller
            menu = null;
        if (elemType === 'a') {
            //anchor clicked, nav back to containing ul
            menu = self.parents('li').not('li#mainmenudrop');
        } else if (elemType === 'li') {
            //mouseleft ul, ergo menu is this.
            menu = self;
        }
        if (menu) {
            menu.hide('medium');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('href.drop').click(function(e) {
            $('li#mainmenudrop li').show('medium');
            console.log('div clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $('li#mainmenudrop a').click(toggleMenu);
        $('li#mainmenudrop li').mouseleave(toggleMenu);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this a lot harder than it needs to be.

You also have issues in your markup and JS

href.drop should have been a.drop

Also an extra closing div.

But thats all besides the point, you don't need all of that JS code

http://jsfiddle.net/DTqDD/

NOTE: you will also want to make some type of fall back for users with JavaScript shutoff.

Comment: the div just pops open rathen then slides, if javascript is disabled in the browser doesnt it just use the normal hover over effect instead?

Comment: @topdown please include the code for your answer in the post. Without that code, your post is useless. If that link 404, your post is useless.